# Need help to find the right regex pattern to match

Tags: javascript, regex

my RegEx is not working the way i think, it should.

`[^a-zA-Z](\d+-)?OSM\d*(?![a-zA-Z])`

I will use this regex in a javascript, to check if a string match with it.

```
Should match:
12345612-OSM34
12-OSM34
OSM56
7-OSM
OSM

Should not match:
-OSM
a-OSM
rOSMann
rOSMa
asdrOSMa
rOSM89
01-OSMann
OSMond
23OSM
45OSM678
```

One line, represents a string in my javascript.

https://www.regex101.com/r/xQ0zG1/3

The rules for matching:

- match `OSM` if it stands alone
- optional match if line starts with digit/s AND is followed by a `-`
- optional match if line ends with digit/s
- match all 3 above combined
- no match if line starts with a character/word except `OSM`
- no match if line end with chracter/word except `OSM`

I Hope someone can help.

Comment: if *match if line ends with digit/s*, why shouldn't `rOSM89` match?

Comment: @Amit because of the starting 'r'

Comment: @Markai - ha? how is the beginning of the line relevant for this rule?

Comment: @Amit You have to take all rules into account when checking a line.

Comment: @Amit, the rules depend on each other.

Comment: These rules are not laid out is a union, and don't make sense as a union. For example, *match OSM if it stands alone* can't work with any other rule.

Comment: @Amit, i`ve updated the rules. Maybe now it is a clearer?

Comment: Not really, but doesn't matter. You have your answer - all that's left is that you accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[^a-zA-Z](\d+-)?OSM\d*(?![a-zA-Z])
```

- `[^a-zA-Z]` In regex, you specify what you want, not what you don't want. This piece of code says there **must** be **one** character that isn't a letter. I believe what you wanted to say is to match the start of a line. You don't need to specify that there's no letter, you're about to specify what there will be on the line anyway. The start of a regex is represented with `^` (outside of brackets). You'll have to use the `m` flag to make the regex multi-line.
- `(\d+-)?` means **one or more digits** followed by a `-` character. The `?` means this whole block isn't required. If you don't want foreign digits, you might want to use `[0-9]` instead, but it's not as important. This part of the code, you got right. However, if you don't need capture blocks, you could write `(?:)` instead of `()`.
- `\d*(?![a-zA-Z])` uses lookahead, but you almost never need to do that. Again, specifying what you don't want is a bad idea because then I could write `OSMé` and it would match because you didn't specify that `é` is forbidden. It's much simpler to specify what is allowed. In your case since you want to match line ends. So instead, you can write `\d*$` which means **zero or more digits** followed by the end of the line.

`/^(?:\d+-)?OSM\d*$/gm` is the final result.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following simplified pattern using anchors:

```
^(?:\d+-)?OSM\d*$
```

The flags needed (if matching multi-line paragraph) would be: `g` for global match and `m` for multi-line match, so that `^` and `$` match the begin/end of each line.

---

### EDIT

Changed the `(\d+-)` match to `(?:\d+-)` so that it doesn't group.

Comment: `()` should be `(?:)` here to avoid grouping

Comment: Ok, in regex101 it is working. But why not in my Javasscript? `function validWmcRegEx(wmc, key) { var re = new RegExp('^(?:\d+-)?' + key * '\d*$', 'gm'); return re.test(wmc); }`. The .test() return always false.

Comment: @danbruegge. You need to double the slashes like `\\\`

Comment: Not working. `... re = new RegExp('^(?:\\d+-)?' + key * '\\d*$', 'gm'); ...`

Comment: @danbruegge Why the `*` after `key`?

Comment: Ah, caps-lock. -.- Thanks. :)